# Statistical tests when each variable in a sample is a percentage

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

I am performing a temperature preference test in mice. Mice are placed into a chamber with one half of a chamber having a cold floor and the other half having a warm floor. Mice spend a specific total time in the chamber (3 min) and can select the cold or warm part of the chamber. I calculate the time (in percent of the total time) spent on each side for each subject (each mouse). The results look like this:

```
Mouse   Warm%   Cold%
    1     85%     15%
    2     80%     20%
    3     87%     13%
    4     84%     16%
```

1. How do I calculate the confidence interval for the mean cold time percentage of the population from which this group of mice was selected?
2. If I perform the same test with a second group of mice which received some experimental treatment, which statistical test to use to check for a difference between two groups of mice?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on how you calculated those percentages, but I will guess at some simple method. If your 85%, for example, means "looked at the mouse 20 times; 17 times it was in the warm" then it's the mean of a binomial (Bernoulli) variable with possible values 0 and 1. Score 0 = cold, 1 = warm, mean 0.85 or 85%.

Note that there is really one percentage being estimated here, as the two sum to 100 by definition.

However, there is a big reservation. Those so-many observations may not be independent. Suppose a mouse prefers warm, so it chooses warm, but then it gets too hot and moves to the cooler bit; or vice versa. You can only treat them as independent if you are confident that your set-up is equivalent to the same number of experiments in which each mouse was observed once and heating and cooling effects don't operate.

For more complicated set-ups, you would probably be best off recasting this as a logit model. That wouldn't solve any dependence problems unless you build those into the model.

Comment: To calculate percentages, I am observing mice continuously with two timers, one of them counting the time on "warm" and the other - on "cold", with the specified rule, that both timers cannot run simultaneously - when one is on, the other is immediatley stopped. So the location of the mouse in unequivocally categorized in either "warm" or "cold" at each moment in time. In the result I get time in seconds (continuous variable) for "warm" and "cold" (e.g. warm 153 sec, cold 27 sec, total 180 sec, cold%=15%).

Comment: I am mostly interested in how I can summarize the data for each group of mice, getting some measure of central tendency and variability. This is in turn needed to see if experimental treatment changes the average time spent on cold side. The research question is really "Does a drug X affect cold sensitivity of mice?"

Comment: Your percentages are thus closer to measured percentages, rather than being based on counting. Some people might want to transform them using logit or angular scale. You could try using standard normal-based methods to compare groups of mice, e.g. anova.

Comment: @Viktor Why is that information not in your question? I'd suggest beta regression as a possibility.

Comment: +1. Beta regression could be better. It respects the bounded response, between 0 and 100%, which anova ignores. You might not find an implementation in all environments. I am familar with `betafit` for Stata. There is also an excellent implementation in R.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg-ext.pdf is a good entry to the literature.

Comment: @Glen_b
My  mistake. I didn't realize it matters. I thought percents are percents no matter how you derived them. Now I kind of understand that they can represent a discrete variable or a continuous variable depending on how you calculated them.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! Beta regression seems like a proper tool to do this. Unfortunately, with my very basic knowledge of statistics (and statistical software - don't know how to use R yet), I am afraid I will be unable to use beta-regression. I believe this method goes beyond the level of a typical biomedical researcher and his software (for instance, SigmaPlot has no such abilities). Unless of course, someone is willing to provide me with a more detailed "for dummies"-style algorithm on how to implement this for my particular problem - testing if the two groups are different ;)

Comment: The only option I see is to compare the two groups with a 2-tailed unpaired t-test. Then my question and concern would be: how much of a problem is that my variable is bounded (from 0 to 100%)? Is it better to use percentage of time (15%) or time in seconds (27 sec, still bounded by 180 sec max time) for this test?

Comment: The impact will depend on how close the means are to the boundaries. There is no difference here between raw data and fraction, as all you are doing is dividing by a constant.

Comment: Is SigmaPlot programable? I have a vague impression that it is not programmable. Your options, it appears, are doing beta regression in some mainstream statistical software and not doing it all. I am a geographer, so I trump you on claims to be a lower life-form.

Comment: @Viktor If you can fit a logistic curve, you can model the proportion while keeping it between 0 and 1.